# Wordpress - Timber - localisation failure

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I'm having trouble to get the localisation / translation functionality to work properly.

Im using the following components:

```
Wordpress 4.4.2
Timber -> Twig
```

The template works fine. Just the localistaion doesnt seem to work.

During my research I came across this post on github, which seems to be incomplete since they dont say anything about how to set it up... 
https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/Text-Cookbook#internationalization

I ended up using the following code - which doesnt work for some reason:

/functions.php

```
class StarterSite extends TimberSite {

function __construct() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
    add_theme_support( 'widgets' );
    add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
    add_filter( 'get_twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_taxonomies' ) );

    $this->register_theme_locals();
    parent::__construct();
}

function register_theme_locals(){
    $path = get_template_directory() . '/languages';
    $result = load_theme_textdomain('panther', $path );

    if ( $result )
        return;

    $locale = apply_filters( 'theme_locale', get_locale(), 'panther' );
    die( "Could not find $path/$locale.mo" );
}
.
.
.
```

/templates/base.twig

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> {{__('Search', 'panther')}}
</button>
```

/languages/en_US.po

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Panther 0.1.20150828\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: http://webklex.com/support/theme/panther\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-11-20 12:58:54+00:00\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: Mon Feb 01 2016 21:29:54 GMT+0100 (CET)\n"
"Last-Translator: admin <info@webklex.com>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: English\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n != 1\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: ..\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _:1;gettext:1;dgettext:2;ngettext:1,2;dngettext:2,3;"
"__:1;_e:1;_c:1;_n:1,2;_n_noop:1,2;_nc:1,2;__ngettext:1,2;__ngettext_noop:1,2;"
"_x:1,2c;_ex:1,2c;_nx:1,2,4c;_nx_noop:1,2,3c;_n_js:1,2;_nx_js:1,2,3c;"
"esc_attr__:1;esc_html__:1;esc_attr_e:1;esc_html_e:1;esc_attr_x:1,2c;"
"esc_html_x:1,2c;comments_number_link:2,3;t:1;st:1;trans:1;transChoice:1,2\n"
"X-Loco-Target-Locale: en_US\n"
"X-Generator: Loco - https://localise.biz/"

#: templates/base.twig:72
msgctxt "submit button"
msgid "Search"
msgstr "Search EN"
```

In order to debug the problem I dumped the translation. Here is the result:
[image]

If I render the view / page I still get the untranslated string:

[image]

I did checked if the correct language has ben loaded and yes it did. I even checked if the correct translation function is called (not the NOOP one) and yes even the right function was called..

I'm kind of lost here. So if anyone has a clue what I'm doin wrong or whats going on, please let me know.

Comment: Did you try moving your `load_theme_textdomain` call inside the `after_setup_theme` hook as advised on the [Codex page for this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain)? Currently it just seems to be called from functions.php, which might be too early.

Comment: did you manage to sort it.

Comment: Hi Purr and Andrew, sorry I answer so late.. Yes I tryed it and its still the same. And no I never found a solution.. Guess I made a mistake somewere else.. I don't know :)

Comment: So `{{ __('Search', 'panther') }}` doesn’t output anything? Did you make sure that `__()` is present in Twig? Before Timber 1.x.x you had to use `TimberHelper::function_wrapper` to enable the function `__()`. But since [Timber 1.0-rc2](https://github.com/timber/timber/releases/tag/1.0-rc2) translation functions are exposed to Twig by default. Did you try updating Timber to the latest version and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it the simple way:

```
function panther_theme_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain('panther', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'panther_theme_setup' ); //this is recommended
```

And for editing/updating the language files, I personally just use the "LOCO Translate" Plugin, since then I don't need an other program to mess around with.

Source: Me, but here too: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_theme_textdomain/